# webpack.config.js for Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js webpack.config.js file to export the AWS and AWSCognito references in my app, but it seems that each of the examples given in the page include either AWS or AWSCognito, but not both. The webpack.config.js syntax itself is not very clear to me, so how would I use both sdk's ?? Do I need to include both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use only one of them. The AWSCognito references the aws-cognito-sdk that contains only the CognitoIdentityServiceProvider service definition which should be enough if all you do is work with User Pools. AWS comes from the aws-sdk which would make sense if you work with other services that are in the main aws sdk such as S3 or DynamoDb.

Comment: Yupp got that now after digging in... But I still got undefined error on AWS for some reason... Don't know how to debug that.